# how to add session start-up program

Tags: linux, ubuntu, startup

**Edited**: How do I programmatically add programs to launch on **user** session startup on Ubuntu?

I know how to perform this operation through Nautilus but I'd like to know how do this through a script.

Comment: What is 'a session' ? Do you mean in X11, ie for you, or when the system boots?

Comment: Oops, missed the "programmatically" bit. Never mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here ya go: The Freedesktop [Autostart specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html).  It's just a matter of writing a .desktop file to the appropriate place.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some program to start with X you could try appending entries to the .xinitrc file, where each entry is something you want to execute with an ampersand (&) attached to it. That's user specific. You can also do something that's specific to your window manager. I use fluxbox so that would be in the ~/.fluxbox/startup file, which is also user specific. I don't know how it works with Gnome, but hopefully the .xinitrc idea will.

If it's just for your purposes you can also make a script called "startup" in your home directory and then add it to the startup programs via the menu, and then have your other script write to this script.